# When trying to check for any updates, why is it taking so long to update the sources?

Tags: update-manager

Every time I try to update it takes forever to update the sources to see if any updates are available. The last update I got was one the update manager then all I get is source update that seems to take forever..

Comment: Please open the update manager let it display all verbose information and when you're feeling that it's stuck again take a screenshot. Executing `sudo apt-get update` would also be helpful to compare, once it's stuck there copy the whole text and paste it here as update of your question. Normally both should be the same. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to problems with some of the Canonical servers (for the Main & US repo's) starting on 05/15. It has been fixed sometime over the last several hr.s & speeds should be back to normal

Answer (score 1):

Well this might also be because the upgrade being new,the servers are loaded as many people are updating...So it takes longer than usual...

Comment: That could very well be, don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see how this is a question, because it's normal too see the repositories take time to update the system and then ubuntu runs some python and perl scripts and all too get the system you have.